# Each UITableViewCell has its own task (Webservice call) and should be reloaded when its task finishes, the task is called every 30seconds

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a UITableView, Each UITableViewCell has its own Async task (Webservice call) , the cell should be notified when its task finishes in order to update the labels, the task is called every 30seconds. I don't want to realod the whole UITableView everytime.

Here is what I have done so far:

```swift
class ViewModel {
    var name, result: String
    var url: String

    init () {
        let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 30, repeats: true, block: self.startUpdating())
    }

    func startUpdating() {
        let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "startUpdating", qos:.utility)
            dispatchQueue.async{
                self.callWebservice()
                // how can i notify my cell about the new changes
        }
    }

    func callWebservice(){
        //call web service and update name and result
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
    let vm = viewModels[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel = vm.name
    cell.detailTextLabel = vm.result
return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update one particular cell instead of reloading the whole TableView.

```
yourTableView.beginUpdates()
yourTableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)
yourTableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: The problem is that i dont have a reference to that cell in my viewmodel

Comment: @MarkFreewind You can manage through by passing indexPath of that particular cell. On completion of your web service you can call your custom delegate to notify the ViewController to update that particular cell.

Comment: Please, `beginUpdates/endUpdates` is completely pointless when calling `reloadRows`

Answer (score 0):

A smart solution is Key Value Observing.

- The model must be a subclass of `NSObject`
- The observed properties must be marked as `@objc dynamic`

  ```
  class ViewModel : NSObject {
      @objc dynamic var name, result: String
  ...
  ```
- In Interface Builder set the style of the cell to `custom`, add two labels and set AutoLayout constraints if needed
- Create a new `UITableViewCell` subclass, name it `ResultCell` and add the two labels and the two observation properties

  ```
  class ResultCell: UITableViewCell {

      @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
      @IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!

      var nameObservation : NSKeyValueObservation?
      var resultObservation : NSKeyValueObservation?
  }
  ```
- In Interface Builder set the class of the custom cell to `ResultCell` and connect the labels to the custom cell
- In the controller in `cellForRow` add the observers

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ResultCell
      let vm = viewModels[indexPath.row]
      cell.nameLabel!.text = vm.name
      cell.resultLabel!.text = vm.result
      cell.nameObservation = vm.observe(\.name, changeHandler: { (model, _) in
          cell.nameLabel!.text = model.name
      })
      cell.resultObservation = vm.observe(\.result, changeHandler: { (model, _) in
          cell.resultLabel!.text = model.result
      })
      return cell
  }
  ```
- And you have to remove the observers in `didEndDisplaying`

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didEndDisplaying cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let resultCell =  cell as! ResultCell
       resultCell.nameObservation = nil
       resultCell.resultObservation = nil
  }
  ```

The benefit is that any change of `name` and `result` in the model will update the cell when it's on screen.